# Filter and replace substring in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I filter `df` rows where `name` contains `Al`, and replace `large` with `L` in `sport`?

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'sport': ['tennis small', 'football medium', 'basketball large']})
```

Expected output:

```
    name    sport
0   Bob     tennis small
1   Jane    football medium
2   Alice   basketball L
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['name'].str.contains('Al'), 'sport'] = df.loc[df['name'].str.contains('Al'), 'sport'].str.replace(r'large', 'L')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter only necessary rows and for them use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), it is better for performance like replace all column without filtering:

```
m = df['name'].str.contains('Al', na=False)
df.loc[m, 'sport'] = df.loc[m, 'sport'].str.replace('large', 'L', regex=True)
print (df)
    name            sport
0    Bob     tennis small
1   Jane  football medium
2  Alice     basketball L
```

---

```
#100 matched values from 30k
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob','Jane','alice'] * 9900 + ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'] * 100, 
                   'sport': ['tennis small','football medium', 'basketball large'] * 10000})

print (df)
        name             sport
0        Bob      tennis small
1       Jane   football medium
2      alice  basketball large
3        Bob      tennis small
4       Jane   football medium
     ...               ...
29995   Jane   football medium
29996  Alice  basketball large
29997    Bob      tennis small
29998   Jane   football medium
29999  Alice  basketball large

[30000 rows x 2 columns]
```

```
In [76]: %%timeit
    ...: m = df['name'].str.contains('Al')
    ...: df.loc[m, 'sport'] = df.loc[m, 'sport'].str.replace('large', 'L', regex=True)
    ...: 
    ...: 
14.6 ms ± 193 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [77]: %%timeit
    ...: df.loc[df.name.str.contains('Al'), 'sport'] = df.sport.str.replace('large', 'L')
    ...: 
    ...: 
34.8 ms ± 254 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [78]: %%timeit
    ...: df['sport'] = np.where(df['name'].str.contains('Al'), df['sport'].str.replace('large', 'L', regex=True),  df['sport'])
    ...: 
    ...: 
35 ms ± 1.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

```
#10k matched values from 30k
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Jane','Alice'] * 10000, 
                   'sport': ['tennis small', 'football medium', 'basketball large'] * 10000})



print (df)


In [80]: %%timeit
    ...: m = df['name'].str.contains('Al')
    ...: df.loc[m, 'sport'] = df.loc[m, 'sport'].str.replace('large', 'L', regex=True)
    ...: 
    ...: 
22.2 ms ± 148 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [81]: %%timeit
    ...: df.loc[df.name.str.contains('Al'), 'sport'] = df.sport.str.replace('large', 'L')
    ...: 
    ...: 
34 ms ± 118 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [82]: %%timeit
    ...: df['sport'] = np.where(df['name'].str.contains('Al'), df['sport'].str.replace('large', 'L', regex=True),  df['sport'])
    ...: 
    ...: 
34.9 ms ± 2.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, thanks for the answer, when applied to more data, it returned `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`, do you know why?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - use `df['name'].str.contains('Al', na=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Try with `loc` and `str.contains` with `str.replace`:

```
df.loc[df.name.str.contains('Al'), 'sport'] = df.sport.str.replace('large', 'L')
```

Example:

```
>>> df.loc[df.name.str.contains('Al'), 'sport'] = df.sport.str.replace('large', 'L')
>>> df
    name            sport
0    Bob     tennis small
1   Jane  football medium
2  Alice     basketball L
>>>
```

Filter the rows where the `name` column contains `Al` and then replace `large` with `L` in the `sports` column.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly you can achieve that with `numpy.where` in conjunction with `str.contains`:

```
import numpy as np

df['sport'] = np.where(df['name'].str.contains('Al'),                     # Condition 
                       df['sport'].str.replace('large', 'L', regex=True), # return if True
                       df['sport'])                                       # return if False
```

```
>>> df
    name            sport
0    Bob     tennis small
1   Jane  football medium
2  Alice     basketball L
```